# Sendgrid API - JSON call

Tags: json, sendgrid

I'm trying to receive data from SendGrid API

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"https://sendgrid.com/api/bounces.get.json",
    data: {api_user:'username',api_key:'userkey',date:1},
    success: function(data){    
        console.log(data)       
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error:function(a,b,c){
        console.log(a);
    }
});
```

**Console shows**:

Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success"}

parsererror

Error: jQuery17208301184673423685_1374648217666 was not called

Where is the bug or issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that SendGrid does not support jsonp.

Unfortunately, switching to plain JSON will not work either, as SendGrid has no CORS headers and browsers will not allow you to access the pages. In short you cannot make AJAX requests dorectly to SendGrid.

However, generally this is for the better as all SendGrid endpoints require authentication and having your username and password in an AJAX request would allow users to take them and then use them to send email.

To get these stats on the frontend, you'll need a server to get them and output them on your domain or a domain with CORS allowances.

Comment: hmmm, that's why it doesn't work. I was talking with support today and it looks that i need to use cURL, Thanks a lot.

Comment: `cURL` would work, but it won't be from JavaScript. Whatever language you're using server side will have some sort of cURL method that will allow you to pull the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes a one click solution!

1. [Deploy](https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/redaxmedia/sendgrid-proxy) your instance of [SendGrid Proxy](https://github.com/redaxmedia/sendgrid-proxy) to Heroku
2. Use `{your-sendgrid-proxy}.herokuapp.com` instead of `api.sendgrid.com`
3. Done (Really)

How it works:

1. It creates a node powered http proxy using [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy)
2. It adds needed headers such as `Authorization` and `Content-Type`
3. It overrides `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` to make your browser `CORS` warning free

See how the [magic](https://github.com/redaxmedia/sendgrid-proxy/blob/master/src/core.js#L17-L39) is working. Feedback is welcome!