# Sending emails through ember?

Tags: email, ember.js, ember-cli

I am currently working on a project using Ember.js and want to send an email with the body containing a generated code that I have built an algorithm to make. My only problem is no matter where I search I can't seem to find a solution to sending emails with Ember as it is a front end framework. Would someone mind pointing me in the right direction as to where I need to go to complete this?

Comment: You can't do this with a frontend framework. You need a backend framework for this.

Comment: Thanks Lux, I was so stumbled on it because a startup I am in the process of joining gave me a task and this was part of it and it was the only thing I couldn't complete. So there is really no way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with an only frontend framework.

But there are some different ways to achive this:

- You can send e-mail by using client machines' email applications. This can be done via `mailto`. [reference1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Creating_an_email_link), [reference2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#Specifying_details). But this does not guarantee to send the e-mail!
- You can send e-mail via a server by using the api's of that server. This can be done in several ways. For example, by using user's mail server's rest api. Such as [outlook rest api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations). Or by using a mail service providers. Such as [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/). For these alternatives, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111233/sending-email-from-static-html-page).