# Ajax POST call not working properly, returns error code 0 even though url POST was successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to invoke the sendgrid api to send email to myself from the 'Contact Us' page on my website.
I have the following jQuery for it:

```js
(function($){
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit-form').click(function(e){
  
   e.preventDefault();
            var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
            var name     = $('#form_name').val(),
    email    = $('#form_email').val(),
    phone    = $('#form_phone').val(),
    date     = $('#form_date').val(),
    message  = $('#form_message').val(),
    data_html,
    success = $('#success'),
    
      if(name == "")
                $('#form_name').val('Please enter your name.');
    
   if(phone == "")
                $('#form_phone').val('Please enter your phone number.');
    
   if(date == "")
                $('#form_date').val('Please enter a date and time.');

            if(email == ""){
                $('#form_email').val('Your email is required.');
            }else if(reg.test(email) == false){
                $('#form_email').val('Invalid Email Address.');
            }
   
            if(message == "")
                $('#form_message').val('Message is required.');

            if(message != "" && name != "" && reg.test(email) != false) {
             text_body = "name=" + name + "&email="+ email + "&message=" + message + "&phone="+ phone + "&date="+ date;
    data_html = "api_user=xxxx&api_key=xxxxxxx&to=xxx@xxx.com&toname=xxx&subject=Test_Subject&text=Test&from=" + email
                alert(data_html);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json',
                    data: data_html,
                    //dataType: 'text',
                    success: function(msg){
      alert('1');
      if (msg == 'sent'){
       alert('2');
                         success.html('<div class="alert alert-success">Message <strong>successfully</strong> sent!</div>')  ;
                            $('#form_name').val('');
       $('#form_phone').val('');
       $('#form_email').val('');
       $('#form_date').val('');
       $('#form_message').val('');
                        }else{
                         alert('3');
                            success.html('<div class="alert alert-error">Message <strong>not</strong> sent! Please Try Again!</div>')  ; 
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                     alert(jqXHR.status);
                     alert(textStatus);
                     alert(':' + thrownError);
                    }
                });
    
            }
            return false;
        });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

I know the jQuery is working called because sendgrid is sending out the email with the provided data.
Problem is, even though sendgrid executed successfully, due to some reason, the ajax call response is going into the error section instead of the success section and I have got no idea as to why.
Below is the value of each of these statements displayed on pop up:

```
alert(jqXHR.status) - 0
alert(textStatus) - error
alert(':' + thrownError) - No popup displayed
```

Below is my html form:

```html
<div class="twelve columns offset-by-two formWrap">
                 <h2>Request a booking</h2>
                    <form action="#" method="post" class="contactForm">
                        <div class="formSecWrap">
                            <input type="text" class="formField" title="Name" id="form_name" name="form_name" value="" />
                            <input type="text" class="formField" title="Email" name="form_email" id="form_email" value="" />
                            <input type="text" class="formField" title="Phone" name="form_phone" id="form_phone" value="" />
                            <input type="text" class="formField" title="Date &amp; Time" name="form_date" id="form_date" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="formSecWrap formSecWrap2">
                            <textarea class="textarea formField" title="Message" name="form_message" id="form_message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                         <input class="button" id="submit-form" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
                        <div id="success"></div>
                        <div id="test-message"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: What do you get for jqXHR.status, textStatus and errorThrown? By the way, you use errorThrown in the function definition and thrownError in the alert.

Comment: The answer states [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827253/sendgrid-api-json-call) that you cannot make AJAX request directly to sendgrid.

Comment: @DaveD - I updated the question with the returned codes. Basically, It returns 0 for xhr.status, error for textStatus and no pop up is displayed for thrownError.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan - I believe that limitation is for jsonp datatype. I am not using either jsonp or json datatype, so in my case, i believe it should be fine, although i might be wrong as i don't have much knowledge on this subject.

Comment: @SourinKSen - If the code you posted accurately reflects what you're running then you won't get a popup for thrownError. Your function definition calls it errorThrown and you refer to it as thrownError. You should see a console error that thrownError is undefined.

Comment: @SourinKSen But you are requesting it directly through AJAX. The problem here is that if you put those `api_key` and `api_user` values in JS everyone are able to see that in your source code and they will use that to send emails. I think that's the reason why they don't allow doing in AJAX directly. What I suggest would be is to have the sendgrid POST in server side(e.g. PHP) then use ajax to trigger that POST in that server side code.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan and therein lies my problem. My site is hosted on GitHub and if GitHub had allowed me to run any server side script, then I could have used PHP to send the emails directly and would not have required to use the sendgrid api, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$('#submit-form').click(function(e){
```

To this:

```
$('#submit-form').submit(function(e){
```

Then move this:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

To the bottom of the submit function. That should work.

Comment: Thanks Brian. However, this change is not really working for me. In fact, with this change, it now refreshes the page and no email is sent out. With 'click', at least was sending out the email even though the response ended up in the error section. Not sure what's causing this.